# Prevent duplicate random code generation?

Tags: php, recursion

I need to prevent generated code from producing duplicate. Is this correct way to do it or are there much more efficient ways?

```
function generate_code ()
{       
    $s = get_random_code();

    // check if code is already in db
    if (is_in_db($s))
        return generate_code();
    else
        return $s;
}
```

Comment: You should add a recursion limit

Comment: @MathieuImbert How do you do that? Is it just counter variable?

Comment: Or you can add a unique variable at the end or start of the code, ie, next available ID of your table, where the codes are stored or the uniqid function in php. That way they will **always** be unique. And the script will run a lot faster.

Comment: Try, http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php or better to embed, time, so you need not check the database

Comment: @IMB You could pass a counter in your function `function generate_code($counter=0)`, then call subsequent functions with `return generate_code($counter + 1);`. Then you can check in your function the value of `$counter`, and throw an Exception for example if it reach the max limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if after generating a code, another duplicated is generated?

```
function generate_code () 
{        
    $s = get_random_code(); 

    // check if code is already in db 
    while (is_in_db($s)) { 
      $s = get_random_code(); 
    } 

    return $s; 
}
```

No need to do recursion.

Answer (score 3):

No need to check database,

```
<?php

    uniqid (rand(), true); 

?>
```

Comment: The problem with `uniqid()` is that you don't get a random distribution as the OP seems to want.

Comment: +1 @MathieuImbert i haved included, rand(). Thanks for indicating

Comment: This solution gives random number without the use of database

Comment: The generated code has custom characters and fixed length of 8 chars, so uniqid() won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop, to avoid possible recursion depth limits:

```
function generate_code ()
{       
    $s = get_random_code();

    // check if code is already in db
    while (is_in_db($s))
        $s = get_random_code();

    return $s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there are.  Concatenate you primarykey, add some unique column, if you want. And hash it. I'm not totally sure, but the risk of getting the same hash from 2 different values is really low. Some says, you are more likely to win the lotto, be destroyed by an asteroid and struck by a lighting at the same time.